# Internet Explorer 11 ignores

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-11

I'm working on a website and IE 11 is not behaving well.

I'm using Bootstrap affix to stick a navigation bar to the top of the page at a certain point.

I also have some anchor links to various parts of the page. the orange basic information is the anchor.

[image: This is what the area looks like from the top]

If I visit one of those links before the nav is fixed in place, IE scrolls to just below the anchor. The anchor is actually off the screen.

[image: This is a bad anchor follow, The anchor is actually off screen]

If I visit the link after the nav has been fixed, there is no problem. The actual anchor is under the nav, but the visual is what is expected.

[image: This is what I want]

I had a similar issue in Firefox but not Chrome. The javascript below fixed the issue with Firefox.

```
$( '#' + page + ' a' ).click( function ( e ) {
  window.location.hash = $( this ).data( 'target' );
  window.location.hash = $( this ).data( 'target' );
} );
```

I could use other methods as well in FF, such as scrollTo, scrollBy, scrollToAnchor, window.location, ...

None of these work with IE 11.

Comment: Where is the relevant HTML markup?  Is your HTML markup compliant with W3C standards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by using empty divs as the anchor point. Putting a `&nbsp;` or some other whitespace character solved the issue.